# Play Framework Configuration - Cache-Control with extension

Tags: playframework

I am trying to clear caching on `index.html` file. We are using Play Framework 2.6.5

As per https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsOverview#Additional-Cache-Control-directive I am trying

```
# application.conf

# Assets configuration
play.assets.cache."/public/index.html"="max-age=0"
```

But when I run this, I am getting following error

```
No configuration setting found for key "/public/index"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.